# How do you know if a char type variable prints a letter or a number?

Tags: java, string, char

I am currently learning java. In some practice problems, when a char variable is printed, it prints an integer. Other times, it prints the actual character represented by the integer in Unicode.

My current "theory" is that whenever you interact with numbers (for ex. add a number to the char), it will print numbers. However, there are exceptions.

```
    char c = 97;
    System.out.println(c); //Prints a (corresponding to lowercase a on ASCII chart)

    char v = 'H';
    Sustem.out.println(v + 5); // Prints 77. Why doesn't it print the string "H5"
```

I expect the ​output of H5 but the actual output is 77.

Comment: H is 72 in ASCII decimal format. Add 5 = 77.. Why it prints 77 and not `M` is because of automatic type-inference where it finds the common type between the two. 5 is an integer so the char is first converted to int, then the addition is done and the result is an integer. Think of why an int + a float is a float.

Comment: In that case, why does char var = 'H';
    char bar = 'A';
    System.out.println(bar + var); //prints 137 I would assume common type between them is char

Comment: The issue here is that all integral types in an arithmetic expression are promoted _at least_ to `int` and the result is then always either an `int` or a `long`, never a `char` or a `short`.

Comment: `System.out.println(v + "5");` // will print H5

Comment: So to answer the question directly, passing a `char` to  `println` _always_ displays the corresponding graphic character.  But if your argument to `println` is an arithmetic expression involving `char`s, you're actually passing an `int`, not a `char`, so you get the decimal representation of that `int`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense...thank you!